# How to calculate values of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the sum of all the values in array in php. Here I have array

```
$_SESSION['price'][];
```

I have some values in the array which has been inserted in to array in each iteration.
when  do `var_dump($_SESSION['price']);` of array I am getting

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "4806" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "65000" } array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "44005" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "215668" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "7896" }
```

now I want to calculate each value i.e `4806`+ `65000`+`44005`+`215668`+`7896`

How can I do this?

I tried `echo "totalsum".array_sum($_SESSION['cart_total']);`

but I got the output

```
totalsum4806totalsum65000totalsum44005totalsum215668totalsum7896
```

Comment: Manipulate your array first.

Comment: Make your values into int / float / double and you should see it work better :)

Comment: It looks like you have a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `array_sum` like as

```
echo array_sum(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));
```

Or for PHP > **5.5.0** You can also use `array_column` like as

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr,0));
```

**Output:**

```
337375
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/gov9M)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have a 2-dimensional array. Every element of `$_SESSION['price']` is an array with one element, rather than a price. I'm not sure why you did it that way, but you'll need to write a loop to access them.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['price'] AS $subarray) {
    $sum += $subarray[0];
}
```

Maybe you should fix whatever is creating the session variable so it makes it a 1-dimensional array. The sub-arrays don't seem to serve any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use `$_SESSION['cart_total']`, but you have to use like `$_SESSION['price']`. When the code is like below

```
$a = array("price" => array("4806", "65000", "44005", "215668", "7896"));
var_dump($a["price"]);
echo "<br>";
echo "totalsum = " . array_sum($a["price"]);
```

The output will look like below

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "4806" [1]=> string(5) "65000" [2]=> string(5) "44005" [3]=> string(6) "215668" [4]=> string(4) "7896" }
totalsum = 337375
```

OR

```
$a["price"][] = array("4806");
$a["price"][] = array("65000");
$a["price"][] = array("44005");
$a["price"][] = array("215668");
$a["price"][] = array("7896");
$sum = 0;
foreach ($a["price"] AS $price) {
    $total += $price[0];
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I've manipulated your array

```
$arr = $_SESSION['price'];

foreach($arr as $key => $val)
{
  $newVal[] = $val[0];
}
print_r(array_sum($newVal)); //output is 337375
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would sum an array like this:

```
$sum = array_sum($_SESSION['price']);
```

However, this will not work for you for two reasons:

1. Your values are not stored as integers, but as strings (hence the `"` in the var dump). (OK, `array_sum` might convert it to an integer for you, so perhaps this is not a problem in practice.)
2. Your values are not stored as elements in the array, but for some reason as single elements in a sub array (hence the `array(1) { [0]=>` in the var dump).

If there are no reasons to why you would want to have it like that, the easiest solution would be to just fix those two things when the array is created, so instead of a nested array of strings you have a flat array of integers.

If that is not possible for some reason, you can sum it like this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['price'] as $e) {
    // Convert the first element of the sub array to integer and add it to the $sum.
    $sum += (int)$e[0];
}
```